# Python и NotePad++

Tags: notepad++

Решил я попробовать написать программу в NotePad++. Потом оказалось что он автоматически добавляет табуляцию и пробелы в одну строку, что вызывает ошибку

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

Не знаете как отформатировать это, чтобы TAB заменялся на пробелы?

Comment: В настройках можно установить какие отступы будут использоваться.

Answer (score 2):

Опции >> Настройки >> Синтаксисы >> CheckBox с текстом "Заменить пробелом" ставим True.